# Expo new project error , How to solve this?

Tags: expo

Error: watch /home/user/Desktop/my-new-project ENOSPC
(node:25859) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

Node -v : v7.6.0 
OS :Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 
Expo : xde-2.20.1-x86_64

it also showing
Warning
Warning: You are using npm version 5.4.2. There may be bugs in this version, use it at your own risk. We recommend version 4.6.1.

Comment: What version of node are you on, what platform? What version of expo?

Comment: node -v :  v7.6.0
OS        :Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS                                                                                 Expo     : xde-2.20.1-x86_64

Comment: What command are you running, I mean, how did you get to this point, what did you do?

Comment: Step 1: Clicked on Create new project button      <br>                                             Step 2: Select Tab Navigation <br>                                                                                  Step 3: Then I wait for download complete after that this error occurred

Comment: You have no more space on your machine, perhaps you are running on a VM?